# SAX parser newline

Tags: java, saxparser

Any idea what am I doing wrong here.

This is the xml file

```
<text xml:space="preserve">{{Redirect|Anarchist|the fictional character|Anarchist (comics)}}
{{Redirect|Anarchists}}
{{Anarchism sidebar}}
{{Libertarianism sidebar}}
</text>
```

Now when I am parsing it with the help of SAX parser, for eg this is my characters method

```
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException{

    System.out.println(text);
    if (text){
        System.out.println(testData); //testData is StringBuilder
        if (testData != null){
            for (int j=start; j < (start + length); j++){
                testData.append(ch[j]);
            }
        }                           
    }
    text = false
}
```

This is my startElement method

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localname, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        text = true;
    }
}
```

but my characters function is called only once. I thought it would be called several times and then I could append the

Comment: Given the code you've provided, I'm surprised that the `characters` function is called even once. I don't see any code that calls the `characters` function...

Comment: Your code won't even compile. Please fix it, then edit your question and put the correct code in. Also, the formatting made the code flow extremely confusing, which i suspect is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Guys, I have just mentioned 2 methods of the SAX Parser. The other methods are startElement and endElement. characters method is called when we set the flag text as true in the startElement method. The code is compiling fine. Just that it reads , {{Redirect|Anarchist|the fictional character|Anarchist (comics)}}
{{Redirect|Anarchists}} 
of the XML file and not the entire text

Answer (score 0):

The "ignore whitespace" flag controls whether the XML parser considers whitespace in between XML elements to be significant or whether it should ignore it. As long as you don't have ignoreWhitespace set, the parser is quite correct in feeding all characters--whitespace or not--to your characters() method.

Comment: Any tips how to implement this flag

Comment: By setting the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/include-ignorable-whitespace". See [Xerces2 Parser Features](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html). But that's only supported by Xerces2. Currently I don't know anything about  a general SAX Parser Feature "ignorable-whitespace".

Comment: I read in this blog http://p2p.wrox.com/xml/41965-sax-ignorewhitespace-method-usage.html wherein he mentions to call the character method again from the ignoreablewhitespace character funtion.
 public void ignorableWhitespace (char buf[], int start, int length) throws SAXException { characters(buf,start,length); }       But it doesnt seem to work. I even tried putting println statement to check if it is being invoked, but i dont think that was happening. Do you think, whitespace and /n are the handled similarly, cos i feel a newline is being encountered

Comment: A new line \n is a [Whitespace Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) and treated as Whitespace by the Parser. The `ignorableWhitespace` is called / used by validating SAXParsers

Comment: A new line \n is a [Whitespace Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) and treated as Whitespace by the Parser. The `ignorableWhitespace` is called / used by validating [SAXParsers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html). The JSE 7 SAXParser supports the Feature "http://java.sun.com/xml/schema/features/report-ignored-element-content-whitespace" which may help.